# UITableView beginUpdates / endUpdates specify animation type

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using a UITableView to display cell with UIWebViews in them. When a web view finishes loading, I adjust the height of the cell by calling

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

This adjusts the height of the cell to meet my needs.

However, it uses a sliding animation, whereas I would like a fade animation. Is there a way to specify this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not exactly clear what you mean by "fade animation", but here are a couple of possibilities:

You can reload the row or rows being resized with the `UITableViewRowAnimationFade` option, which will cause the reloaded row to cross fade to the new state while the cells below slide down:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Or, you can cross-disolve the entire table and not have any sliding animation at all:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:tableView duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
} completion:nil];
```